# XStream: How to do validation after deserialization

Tags: java, bean-validation, xstream

I like to validate my bean using bean-validation after it is read using xstream.

I try to implement readObject(), but this way I have to do the whole deserialization on my own, and that is definitively not what I wanted.

Is there any method called after deserialization, I can override?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is all right, you are just missing a few small things.

If you want the default serialization to take place, you can overwrite the readResolve method as you would with standard Java Serialization API

(method `private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException`) and call `in.defaultReadObject();` in that method.

Afterwards you could call your validation methods, or initialize transient fields or do whatever you want after deserialization.

This is also explained in more detail on the [XStream FAQ](http://x-stream.github.io/faq.html#Serialization_initialize_transient).